# Consistent disconnection by VAC in Linux, despite verifying local file integrity

Tags: steam, technical-issues, team-fortress-2, linux

I got disconnected from an official Team Fortress 2 server by VAC using my Linux machine, even though I have not changed the game files in anyway nor have I added any modifications. Yet, after verifying the integrity of the game files twice, I'm still being disconnected. Rebooting the machine doesn't seem to help either.

I don't have my firewall activated, I use GUFW; this just happened spontaneously.

What is causing the issue and how should I fix it? If all else fails, I might as well reinstall the game.

Comment: This question may sound silly - [do you have any users on your machine with the name 'catbot'?](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/2475)

Comment: No. There is no user called "catbot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Linux-specific issue that has been fixed by Valve as of 20-01-2018

References:

- https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/1693785035813219301/
- https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/2502
- https://github.com/ValveSoftware/csgo-osx-linux/issues/1596

Answer (score -1):

If you did name someone named catbot or anything that sounds remotely like catbot steam will auto ban it on TF2. This was something they confirmed. It sucks, but they have it to prevent spam and hacker accounts.

Comment: No. There is no user called "catbot". I'm not auto banned anyways, I'm just denied from connecting to the Valve server.

Comment: Reading around, this username VAC ban stuff seems to have just  been a hoax.  A Valve employee stated that they do not do this in [this reddit](https://np.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/7ndjdt/valve_will_vac_ban_you_automatically_for_having/ds2dulw/)

Comment: Yeah, the catbot drama was an attempt from the scum of the earth creators/users of the catbot TF2 cheat to try to get some attention...for no logical reason. If people actually bothered to look into the creator of the threads on Reddit and the Issue(s) on GitHub it's very easily noticeable.